# 404 Error While URL Routing with asp.net web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am implementing url routing in my asp.net web forms. 
**This is my mapping class**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "User",
            "Users/{id}",
            "~/Modules/UserMgmt/Users.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Leave",
            "LeaveApply/{id}",
            "~/Modules/LeaveMgmt/LeaveApply.aspx");
    }
}
```

I am calling this method in my Application Start

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

and this is my anchor tag

```
<a href="/Users/18">Users</a>
```

Its working fine when I configure the project with "**Use Visual Studio Development Server**" from the project properties.

[image]

and its working fine as shown below

[image]

When I configure run the project with "**Use Local IIS Web Server**" from the project properties. ie)

[image]

I am getting the error shown below
[image]

The route directory or project name(Created when configure with "**Use Local IIS Web Server**" ) is missing while Routing. When I put the directory name add directly to the url from browser its working. Shown below.

[image]

Could you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: check the textbox `override application root`

Answer (score -1):

Your routing is working fine, other wise you havn't see results for localhost/URLRouting/Users/18
However, there is no website listening to 'localhost' address.

If you want to use localhost, open IIS Manager, Create WebSite under the root and map it to your project physical folder.

Remove 'UrlRouting' from the project web properties